# How to use zerofree on Fedora 34? It won't open file system

Tags: mount

I'm using Fedora 34 on VirtualBox. I booted into rescue mode from Live CD then I tried to run `zerofree` on it but it won't open file system. The error was "failed to open file system" The mounting was  also in trouble. I input `mount -o remount,ro /dev/sda2` and got the error `mount point not mounted or bad option`. How do I fix this? I also tried `sudo zerofree` which also doesn't work. Been google around for hours and only found information of Ubuntu, can't apply any of them to my case

Comment: It is best to run zerofree, when a partition (file system) is **not** mounted. I think it works only with ext2, ext3 and ext4 file systems. What file system are you using? If you want to address the file system in `/dev/sda2`, did you try `sudo zerofree /dev/sda2` ?

Comment: Yes I did. It gave the same result. I'm on ext2

Comment: I used zerofree on Ubuntu a few years ago, and it worked as expected. I have not used it on Fedora, and not on VirtualBox. **Why do you want to run it?** I find the following text in one version of `man zerofree`: "zerofree  has been written to be run from GNU/Linux systems installed as guest OSes inside a virtual machine. In this case, it is typically run from within the guest system,  and  a utility  is  then  run  from  the  host  system  to shrink disk image (`VBoxManage modifyhd --compact`, provided with virtualbox, is able to do that for some disk image formats)."

Comment: I want to shrink the image file. I did it on ubuntu guest without problem, booted in rescue mode and remounted ro it before running zerofree. But on Fedora guest it just cant get through

Comment: I don't know much about Fedora and can't tell why `zerofree` should fail there. You should get the same final result by creating a file with `dd` until the file system is full, and then delete that file. It might be slower than `zerofree`, but it is likely to work in Fedora, so I suggest that you try it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this?  First issue I see is your mount command, you don't give a mount point (that explains the error).  Create a mount point (eg: mkdir /mnt/temp) then mount your /dev/sda2 ONTO that mount point.

Next, in response to comments this is useful if you want to 'dd' a whole drive for backup, but don't want to backup unused space.  (It will compress all the zeroes to a few bytes)

Answer (score 0):

#### TL/DR

Run this as `root` in recovery mode:

```
# echo "u" > /proc/sysrq-trigger
# mount /dev/mapper / -o remount,ro
# zerofree -v /dev/sda<THE_DRIVE_NUMBER>
```

#### Long answer

I found the answer [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2399268.html):

Ensure you have a root password:

```
$ sudo passwd -u root
$ sudo passwd root
```

Type in a password you can remember.

Reboot

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

When you see the VirtualBox logo screen, hold down the [RIGHT SHIFT] key until you see the grub screen.
Select the advanced options and then recovery mode.
At the next screen select to drop to root console.
At the `#` prompt enter the root password you set earlier.

```
# mount | grep "sda"
```

Take note of the `sda` number (ie. `sda1`, `sda2`, etc.) that is for the `/` or root directory. We'll assume `/dev/sda2` for this example.

```
# echo "u" > /proc/sysrq-trigger
# mount /dev/mapper / -o remount,ro
# zerofree -v /dev/sda2
# shutdown -r now
```

*NOTE: You don't need to remount as `rw` after using `zerofree` because once you reboot `fstab` will mount the drive `rw` anyway.*

Now let it boot normally.

If you want to disable your root password (I am one of those that does this for security reasons):

```bash
$ sudo passwd -l root
```

Now I usually just go and shut down the system and compress the drive:

```bash
$ sudo shutdown -hP now
```